# Unable to remove underline from an anchor link in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I can't remove the underline from an anchor with a link. Using `style="text-decoration:none"` doesn't work when I try adding it inline with the element and in the CSS. I believe my problem exists somewhere else in the CSS but I'm not sure.

[This is the underline I'm trying to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6F1SB.png)

This is the problem HTML with the href link:

I used the CSS reset https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ at the start of my CSS code.

```css
body {
    background: #262d47;
    color: #888;
    font: 300 16px/22px "Raleway", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/*
    ================================
    Grid
    ================================
*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container,
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1196px;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.grid,
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Clearfix
  ========================================
*/
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}

/*
    ================================
    Typography
    ================================
*/

h1, h3, h4, h5, p {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  color: #92d4cc;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 400;
}
cite, em {
  font-style: italic;
}
p {
    color: #FFF;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Links
  ========================================
*/
a {
  color: #92d4cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}
p a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #92d4cc;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Buttons
  ========================================
*/
.btn {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.btn-alt {
    border: 1px solid #92d4cc;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary header
  ========================================
*/

.logo {
  border-top: 4px solid #92d4cc;
  float: left;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 40px 0 22px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tagline {
  margin: 66px 0 22px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.primary-nav {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary footer
  ========================================
*/

.primary-footer {
  color: #92d4cc;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 44px;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
.primary-footer small {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Navigation
  ========================================
*/
.nav {
  text-align: right;
}


/*
  ========================================
  Home
  ========================================
*/
.hero {
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 22px 80px 66px 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.hero p {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.teaser a:hover h3 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}

/*
  ========================================
  About box 
  ========================================
*/
.about {
    color: #92d4cc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.marxist {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="teaser col-1-3">
    <a href="venue.html">
        <h5>Venue</h5>
        <h3>The beautiful Theater</h3>
    </a>
    <p>The beautiful historical theater will be our conference venue.<a class="marxist" href="https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/">&#9773;</a></p>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Underline problem is coming because of below code:

```
p a {
/*border-bottom: 1px solid #92d4cc;*/
}
```

I have comment the above code and everything is working as you asked.

check the below snippet for the solution.

let me know if you need any other help.

```css
/*
  ========================================
  Custom styles
  ========================================
*/
body {
    background: #262d47;
    color: #888;
    font: 300 16px/22px "Raleway", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/*
    ================================
    Grid
    ================================
*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container,
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1196px;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.grid,
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Clearfix
  ========================================
*/
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}

/*
    ================================
    Typography
    ================================
*/

h1, h3, h4, h5, p {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  color: #92d4cc;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 400;
}
cite, em {
  font-style: italic;
}
p {
    color: #FFF;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Links
  ========================================
*/
a {
  color: #92d4cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}
p a {
  /*border-bottom: 1px solid #92d4cc;*/
}

/*
  ========================================
  Buttons
  ========================================
*/
.btn {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.btn-alt {
    border: 1px solid #92d4cc;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary header
  ========================================
*/

.logo {
  border-top: 4px solid #92d4cc;
  float: left;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 40px 0 22px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tagline {
  margin: 66px 0 22px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.primary-nav {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary footer
  ========================================
*/

.primary-footer {
  color: #92d4cc;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 44px;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
.primary-footer small {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Navigation
  ========================================
*/
.nav {
  text-align: right;
}


/*
  ========================================
  Home
  ========================================
*/
.hero {
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 22px 80px 66px 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.hero p {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.teaser a:hover h3 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}

/*
  ========================================
  About box 
  ========================================
*/
.about {
    color: #92d4cc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.marxist {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<section class="teaser col-1-3">
            <a href="venue.html">
                <h5>Venue</h5>
                <h3>The beautiful Theater</h3>
            </a>
            <p>The beautiful historical theater will be our conference venue.<a class="marxist" href="https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/">&#9773;</a></p>
          </section>
```

Answer (score 2):

you must remove the `border-bottom` from `matrix`.

```css
body {
    background: #262d47;
    color: #888;
    font: 300 16px/22px "Raleway", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/*
    ================================
    Grid
    ================================
*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container,
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1196px;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.grid,
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Clearfix
  ========================================
*/
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}

/*
    ================================
    Typography
    ================================
*/

h1, h3, h4, h5, p {
    margin-bottom: 22px;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4 {
  color: #92d4cc;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 400;
}
cite, em {
  font-style: italic;
}
p {
    color: #FFF;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Links
  ========================================
*/
a {
  color: #92d4cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}
p a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #92d4cc;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Buttons
  ========================================
*/
.btn {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}
.btn-alt {
    border: 1px solid #92d4cc;
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary header
  ========================================
*/

.logo {
  border-top: 4px solid #92d4cc;
  float: left;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 40px 0 22px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tagline {
  margin: 66px 0 22px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.primary-nav {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary footer
  ========================================
*/

.primary-footer {
  color: #92d4cc;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 44px;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
.primary-footer small {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Navigation
  ========================================
*/
.nav {
  text-align: right;
}


/*
  ========================================
  Home
  ========================================
*/
.hero {
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 22px 80px 66px 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.hero p {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.teaser a:hover h3 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}

/*
  ========================================
  About box 
  ========================================
*/
.about {
    color: #92d4cc;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.marxist {
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none !important;
border-bottom : none;
}
```

```html
<section class="teaser col-1-3">
    <a href="venue.html">
        <h5>Venue</h5>
        <h3>The beautiful Theater</h3>
    </a>
    <p>The beautiful historical theater will be our conference venue.<a class="marxist" href="https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/">&#9773;</a></p>
  </section>
```

Comment: I agree. Only border bottom is the issue

Answer (score 2):

Just change below in css :

```
.marxist { color: #fff; text-decoration: none !important; border: none;}
```

```css
/*
  ========================================
  Custom styles
  ========================================
*/
body {
  background: #262d47;
  color: #888;
  font: 300 16px/22px "Raleway", "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial,
    sans-serif;
}

/*
    ================================
    Grid
    ================================
*/
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container,
.grid {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1196px;
}
.container {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
}
.grid,
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.col-1-3,
.col-2-3 {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
.col-2-3 {
  width: 66.66%;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Clearfix
  ========================================
*/
.group:before,
.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.group:after {
  clear: both;
}
.group {
  clear: both;
  *zoom: 1;
}

/*
    ================================
    Typography
    ================================
*/

h1,
h3,
h4,
h5,
p {
  margin-bottom: 22px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4 {
  color: #92d4cc;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 44px;
}
h3 {
  font-size: 21px;
}
h4 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
h5 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
strong {
  font-weight: 400;
}
cite,
em {
  font-style: italic;
}
p {
  color: #fff;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Links
  ========================================
*/
a {
  color: #92d4cc;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}
p a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #92d4cc;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Buttons
  ========================================
*/
.btn {
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
}
.btn-alt {
  border: 1px solid #92d4cc;
  padding: 10px 30px;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary header
  ========================================
*/

.logo {
  border-top: 4px solid #92d4cc;
  float: left;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 40px 0 22px 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.tagline {
  margin: 66px 0 22px 0;
  text-align: right;
}
.primary-nav {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Primary footer
  ========================================
*/

.primary-footer {
  color: #92d4cc;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 44px;
  padding-top: 44px;
}
.primary-footer small {
  float: left;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Navigation
  ========================================
*/
.nav {
  text-align: right;
}

/*
  ========================================
  Home
  ========================================
*/
.hero {
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 22px 80px 66px 80px;
  text-align: center;
}
.hero h2 {
  font-size: 36px;
}
.hero p {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 100;
}
.teaser a:hover h3 {
  color: #a9b2b9;
}

/*
  ========================================
  About box 
  ========================================
*/
.about {
  color: #92d4cc;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.marxist {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="teaser col-1-3">
  <a href="venue.html">
    <h5>Venue</h5>
    <h3>The beautiful Theater</h3>
  </a>
  <p>The beautiful historical theater will be our conference venue.<a class="marxist" href="https://www.marxists.org/archive/marx/works/1848/communist-manifesto/">&#9773;</a></p>
</section>
```